# How can I add custom data to textview in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to JAVA and Android. Previously, I was working on Javascript & Jquery.

As in HTML using Javascript (or Jquery) we can add custom data attribute to any element. for example-

```
$("#element").data("customdata", "customvalue");
```

And later I can get the value by doing-

```
var customvalue = $("#element").data("customdata");
```

Is there any method available in Android to achieve this type of thing?

Like, if I need to set multiple type of strings to a single TextView and later get them as needed.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple type of strings ?. Do you have a pic of your desired output?

Comment: I meant to say I want to attach some details about a product to a textview and later on selecting that view, i need to read the details.
For example, there is a textview with a product name. In it I want to attach its stockid, current stock and its selling price. so that, whenever I select that view i can get the details.
Here is a sample fiddle on javascript - [link](https://jsfiddle.net/funbinod/d01egwa5/1/). I wish things happen in the same way. Sorry, if my explanation is again unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your textview from XML and set text on it . Something like this

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textview_id);
textView.setText("Your awesome text");

// Later fetch the text details back
String textDetails = textView.getText().toString();
```

This is a basic code sample of how to add and retrieve text from the text-view. Hope this help your case

Comment: adding and getting text is not enough for me. i need other data also. as i explained in your previous comment, I need to attach more details like stock id, its current quantity and its selling price. Setting and getting text can give me only stock name.

Comment: These other details ..are these visible to user in the text view or not?

Comment: It doesn't matter, whether they are displayed or not. What matters is, I want to reuse them, multiple times. Like I can create some other fields that can hold the same data. I can setID() to the view, but it is not enough. Just like we set and get ID to any element, my question is, is it possible to set and get more data to it?

Comment: I think better to use a class object to store those data...and retrieve them later as required..hence you would have flexibility over what to display and what data to retrieve

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Will that work for multiple views? If I have 10 items to store their own data, does storing them to a single class work? Can you suggest me an example?

Comment: Yes..u can store them as a List of class objects. You can search for how classes are created in Java and creating a list in Java. Also if you have multiple items to view I would suggest using a recycler view for it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the View's setTag() and getTag() for that purpose.

However, most of the time there are cleaner ways like using ViewModel architecture etc. but that is a different story.

Comment: This looks like a good answer. But I'm quite unfamiliar to this. Can you explain, how can i do this? And one more question on it. Is there any limitations for the number of tags to a single element??? How many tags can i set to a single TextView?

Comment: There's a setTag(Object) method you can use to set anything, even a Map or a custom object with arbitrary data, and there's a setTag(id, Object) to set any number of tags. Please check the javadoc yourself, as this would become too broad otherwise. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setTag()

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This sounded good suggestion. I read the documentation also. But I found that the tag "id" should be a Integer only. Is it so? If so how can I set tag for quantity and price? I tried setTag("cqty", "25") and getTag("cqty"), but this didnot work. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I saw your link. I think you can use AlertDialog.
this is my code.I think you would need it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   EditText e1;
    TextView t4;
   Buttob btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t4);
        t4.setOnClickListener(t4click);
        e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e1);
       btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
      btn.setOnClickListener(btnlogin);

    }

 private Button.OnClickListener btnlogin=new Button.OnClickListener(){
    //click button

        public void onClick(View v){
            String account=e1.getText().toString();//get edittext value
            String tmp="";
            tmp=t4.getText().toString()+account; //get textview value and add 
  edittext string
            t4.setText(tmp);//insert new value
            }
        }
    };
    private TextView.OnClickListener t4click=new TextView.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
    //if click textview it,would show dialog
   //if your dialog value is from edittext ,you can reuse it.
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("product")

                    .setMessage("item:pen"+"\nid=A001"+"\nprice:10 USD")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i)
                        {
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But sorry for the confusion. The alert menu on the jsfiddle was just for sample. Just displaying a alert menu is not my motive. I want to reuse them. There will be multiple such views holding their own data. Like, when I click any of them, I wish some other fields like EditText, Button will be creating holding the same data. (Does it sound complicated?)

Comment: Binod Anuj,I think I know your problem,so I have edit my code,try it.

Comment: can u please explain the code? what is "t2" that you are getting text from? that you have not declared anywhere in the code. and again, you have not said how can i reuse the AlertDialog message.

Comment: sorry,I make a mistake ,is t4 not t2, and you can reuse AlertDialog, if you store message in parameter,it can insert in textview, I have write explain in code